# How to combine integration equation in Python?

Tags: python, integration, distribution

I'm calculating key rate (R^Rate-wise) by integrating R(eta) over all possible eta from 0 to 1, with a probability distribution (PDTC) which is a log-normal distribution.

The equation of log-normal distribution:

[image]

The equation of R(eta):

[image]

Therefore, R^Rate-wise = Integrate_0^1(R(eta)*P(eta)*d eta):

[image]

This is Python code of log-normal distribution:

```
x=np.linspace(0,1,1000)
sigma0=[0.9]
color=['green']
for i in range(len(sigma0)):
    sigma=sigma0[i]
    y=1/(x*sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(np.log(x/0.3)+(1/2*sigma*sigma))**2/(2*sigma*sigma))
    plt.plot(x,y,color[i])
plt.title('Lognormal distribution')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('lognormal density distribution')
#plt.xlim((0,0.002))
plt.ylim((0,5))
plt.show()
```

This is Python code of R(eta):

```
n1=np.arange(10, 55, 1)
n=10**(-n1/10)


Y0=1*(10**-5)
nd=0.25
ed=0.03
nsys=nd*n
QBER=((1/2*Y0)+(ed*nsys))/(Y0+nsys)
H2=-QBER*np.log2(QBER)-(1-QBER)*np.log2(1-QBER)
Rsp=np.log10((Y0+nsys)*(1-(2*H2)))
print (Rsp)

plt.plot(n1,Rsp)
plt.xlabel('Loss (dB)')
plt.ylabel('log10(Rate)')
plt.show()
```

My question is how to integrate R(eta) over possible eta from 0 to 1? The output should be in the following figure (R^Rate-wise):
[image]

The referred article can be find in this link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.08949.pdf

Comment: How about using https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. How to plot it into the graph?

Comment: There are various plotting libraries you can use, of which (I believe) [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) is the most famous :)

Comment: 0 is special for the log-normal distribution, but 1 is not—why integrate over the unit interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what range of values of eta you are trying to integrate over so i chose `x = np.linspace(0,2,1000)` and organized the code little bit to make it suitable for `scipy.integrate.quad`.

```
x=np.linspace(0,2,1000)

def log_normal(x,sigma):
    y=1/(x*sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(np.log(x/0.3)+(1/2*sigma*sigma))**2/(2*sigma*sigma))

    return y


def R(x,nd,Y0,ed):
    nsys = x*nd
    QBER=((1/2*Y0)+(ed*nsys))/(Y0+nsys)
    H2=-QBER*np.log2(QBER)-(1-QBER)*np.log2(1-QBER)
    out = (Y0+nsys)*(1-(2*H2))
    return out


def out(x,nd,Y0,ed,sigma):

    term1 = log_normal(x,sigma)
    term2 = R(x,nd,Y0,ed)

    return term1*term2

hyp = (0.25,1*(10**-5), 0.03,0.9) #nd,Y0,ed,sigma


lg = log_normal(x[1:],hyp[3])

r = R(x[1:],hyp[0],hyp[1],hyp[2])
plt.plot(lg,label = "log_normal sigma = 0.9")
plt.plot(r,label = "R")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.plot(np.log10 ( out(x,hyp[0],hyp[1],hyp[2],0.9) ),label = "sigma = 0.9" )
plt.plot(np.log10 ( out(x,hyp[0],hyp[1],hyp[2],0.3) ) ,label = "sigma = 0.3")
plt.plot(np.log10 ( out(x,hyp[0],hyp[1],hyp[2],0.6) ) ,label = "sigma = 0.6")

#plt.xlim((0,50))
#plt.ylim((-10,0))
plt.title("Rate")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

And now we can integrate out.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

sol = quad(out,a = 0,b =1 ,args=hyp)
sol
#(0.03721392434457473, 1.9175746760101603e-10)
```

Comment: Thank you @Siddhant Tandon for your response and codes. Is it necessary to use `scipy.integrate` in order to plot this graph?

Comment: I think no, because what you want in your plot is rate which is `dR/dη = R(η)P(η)` on the `y-axis`. When you integrate this equation with respect to `dη` between the limits `0 and 1` you will get a single numerical value as this is a definite integral.

Comment: to plot the above you just need to multiply your functions `R(η)` and `P(η)` and accordingly substitute the correct hyper-params and range of `η` values to reproduce the graphs mentioned in that paper.